# Ant JUnit Batchtest .java or .class

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have seen a few links which appears to imply that JUnit tests can be executed from the .java file instead of the .class

For example

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" haltonerror="yes">
        <classpath refid="ui.tests.classpath"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest todir="${env.WORKSPACE}/UITests/output">
            <fileset dir="${ui.tests.classes}">
                <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Instead of

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" haltonerror="yes">
        <classpath refid="ui.tests.classpath"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest todir="${env.WORKSPACE}/UITests/output">
            <fileset dir="${ui.tests.classes}">
                <include name="**/*Test.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
```

Is the first example a valid case? I could not get it working due to ClassNotFoundExceptions

Comment: According to the Ant [API](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) for the junit task the first one is a valid case.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment above, that it looks like the  tag allows for either .java or .class.

I did a small test and when I ran a test with this setup - where the `dir=somefolder`, then using `<include name="**/*Test.java"/>` when the folder pointed at contains class files, then Ant will basically have an empty fileset to process for *Test.java, but when using `<include name="**/*Test.class"/>` then the fileset was not empty and the test cases will get run.

This was the result of my quick test.  As far as I could tell, it looks like you need to specify the *Test.class to pickup the test cases.